# How to Batch Update Products?

Tags: product, batch-processing, bigcommerce

The existing questions mention that you can't do batch product updates, but BigCommerce has a page for batch updates now:

[Big Commerce Batch Product Update Documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/products/updateproducts)

However, it says it's limited to 10 items.  Is this for updates only and not new products?  What about custom fields?  If you specify custom fields, do those replace any existing ones or only update them?  What if you want to add or delete custom fields?  Do you have to do it one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

It is true about the limit -- you can only update 10 products at a time. This is an update, which requires the product to already exist. In regards to custom fields, you can modify them with this endpoint -- it will overwrite the custom field as you must include an identifier (being name) with the request. [image] If you wanted to add or delete custom fields, you would use a different endpoint. To create a custom field on a product, you'd use: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-custom-fields/createcustomfield and to delete a custom field on a product, you'd use: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-custom-fields/deletecustomfieldbyid

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking to improve the speed of updates by putting them into batches.  Our existing process uses the endpoints you mentioned to add, update, and delete the custom fields.  The fact that the batch update can only update existing custom fields prevents us from being able to use it.  It would be nice to have a way to send large batches of product updates, either through the API or through an FTP site where we could post large update files and have them automatically processed.

Comment: Hi @Randy, this would not be via api, but you could look at importing products: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Importing-Exporting-Products